# Android: create space-around (equal space) between elements and borders

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have two imageView widgets and I would like to place them so that there is equal space between the left border and the left image, the left image and the right image, and the right image and the right border. (I wrote in the title of the question space-around because it's similar to the spacing used in CSS...)

Is it possible to achieve without manual adaptation (such as calculating margins)? And is it possible to achieve solely in the design mode without writing xml code?

Screen shot:
[image]

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/newbackground"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRoll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3498db"
        android:text="@string/btnRoll"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="167dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="621dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dice1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="59dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dice2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="267dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="406dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/newbackground"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRoll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#3498db"
            android:text="btnRoll"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btnRoll"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/blue_heart" />

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btnRoll"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/blue_heart" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Nilesh it's working! Btw it seems that the horizontalBias of the first ImageView isn't required, why did you add it? Anyhow thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposition with a LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
  <View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
  <ImageView ... />
  <View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
  <ImageView ... />
  <View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
  <ImageView ...
</LinearLayout>
```

With the `layout_weight` attribute, the "spacer" views will take the maximum of free space, equally